# Reducing logical operators in Perl 6

Tags: raku

I'm trying to reduce `and` and get a strange output:

```perl6
> [and] 2>1, 3>2, put 1, put 2
2
1True
```

Meanwhile if I put `and` between each expression, everything is OK.

```perl6
> 2>1 and 3>2 and put 1 and put 2
1
2
```

What's the reason of this difference?

Comment: Note that `put 1` returns `True`, and `put 1, put 2` is the same as `put (1, put 2)`. What are you trying to achive with the put statements?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thanks! Putting parentheses solved the problem: `[and] 2>1, 3>2, (put 1), (put 2)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To elaborate on Håkon's comment.  The difference is in precedence.

The two statements are equivalent to these:

```
> [and] (2>1), (3>2), (put 1,(put 2))
2
1True
> (2>1) and (3>2) and (put 1) and (put 2)
1
2
```

In the first case, it first evaluates `put 2`, printing the `2` and returning `True`, then the `put 1,True`, printing `1True`, returning `True`. The whole expression evaluates to `True`, but doesn't print anything more.

In the second case, The `put 1` evaluates first, printing the `1` and returning `True`, then the `put 2` evaluates, printing the `2` and also returning `True`.  Again, the whole expression evaluates to True but doesn't print anything more.